# Why does Hibernate saves my entities list several times?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I'm currently working on a Spring-boot application written in Kotlin. I'm writting an API which permits a logged user to add a metro station or a metro line to his favorite (and have informations about it more quickly).
My users are represented by the `ApplicationUser` class with a username, a password, a set of his favorite metro lines, and another set for his favorite metro stations.

I have written a controller to allow **logged in** users adding a line or a station to their favorites. I also have written a function which return the current user. This is how my controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/favorites")
class FavoriteController(private val applicationUserRepository: ApplicationUserRepository,
                         val lineService: LineService,
                         val stationService: StationService,
                         private var currentUser: ApplicationUser?) {

    private fun provideCurrentUser() : ApplicationUser? {
        if(this.currentUser == null) {
            val currentUsername: String = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal.toString()
            this.currentUser = this.applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(currentUsername)
        }
        return this.currentUser
    }


    @PostMapping
    fun addFavorite(@RequestParam(value = "type", required = true)type: FavoriteType?,
                    @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true)id: Long?) : ResponseEntity<String> {
        return if(provideCurrentUser() == null || type == null || id == null) {
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("You have to be logged and provide the type " +
                    "and the id of the desired entity in order to add it to your favorites list")
        } else {
            when(type) {
                FavoriteType.STATION -> {provideCurrentUser()?.addToFavorites(this.stationService.findById(id) as Station)
                    this.applicationUserRepository.save(provideCurrentUser() ?: throw Exception("User Not found"))}
                FavoriteType.LINE -> {provideCurrentUser()?.addToFavorites(this.lineService.findById(id) as Line)
                    this.applicationUserRepository.save(provideCurrentUser() ?: throw Exception("User Not found")) }
                FavoriteType.UNKNOWN -> return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("Unknown entity type")
            }
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("The $type with id $id has been successfully added to your favorites")
        }
    }
```

I thought it was working but it actually raises an exception after three calls. Both first and second call works fine, but if call this function a third time, an exception is raised due to duplicate primary key in the database. I use JpaRepository functions to manage my entities (save).
i assume this issue could come from an early closing of the transaction, but I don't know how to check if it's right, or how to fix it...

here is the code of my ApplicationUser class if you need it:

```
@Entity
class ApplicationUser(val username: String = "",
                      var password: String = "",
                      @ManyToMany(cascade= [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
                      @JoinTable(name="user_favstation", joinColumns= [JoinColumn(name="user_id")], inverseJoinColumns=[JoinColumn(name="station_id")])
                      @CollectionId(
                              columns = [Column(name="COLLECTION_ID")],
                              type= Type(type="long"),
                              generator = "sequence"
                      )
                      var favoriteStations: MutableList<Station> = mutableListOf(),
                      @ManyToMany(cascade= [CascadeType.ALL] , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
                      @JoinTable(name="user_favline", joinColumns= [JoinColumn(name="user_id")], inverseJoinColumns=[JoinColumn(name="line_id")])
                      @CollectionId(
                              columns = [Column(name="COLLECTION_ID")],
                              type= Type(type="long"),
                              generator = "sequence"
                      )
                      var favoriteLines: MutableList<Line> = mutableListOf())
    : BaseEntity() {

    fun addToFavorites(station: Station): Boolean {
        return this.favoriteStations.add(station)
    }

    fun addToFavorites(line: Line): Boolean {
        return this.favoriteLines.add(line)
    }

    fun deleteFavorite(station: Station): Boolean {
        return this.favoriteStations.remove(station)
    }

    fun deleteFavorite(line: Line): Boolean {
        return this.favoriteLines.remove(line)
    }
}
```

Here is the exception stacktrace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1567) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3245) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at fr.asi.controllers.FavoriteController.addFavorite(FavoriteController.kt:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at fr.asi.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.kt:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191
```

**EDIT:** I modified my ApplicationUser class by adding @CollectionId annotation above my two list of favorites. Since this annotation doesn't work with MutableSet, I change them to MutableList. Now my controller doesn't raise any exception BUT I found that every time I try to add a favorite hibernate add EVERY favorites again. After adding **only 4 stations** to my favorites, my favorite stations table looks like this (and I don't know why) :
[image: favorite stations table]

I hope someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace ofexception you are getting?

Comment: @Ctorres you are getting duplicate primary key for which entity? Is it for ApplicationUser or Line or Station?

Comment: @ShubhDixit I edited my question and added the stacktrace

Comment: Isn't *Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'PRIMARY'* self explainatory?

Comment: @Antoniossss Could you explain me please? I don't get why the exception is raised at the third call. Maybe you could write an answer if you know how to fix this.

Comment: @ordonezalex The line 38 of FavoriteController is a calling of save method from my JpaRepository. I add it to my question if you need.

Comment: You need to use a debugger and find out when/why entry 1-4 is created in your table. Step through it, keep checking the entries after each step.